# jQuery 'draggable' images not all active when used with 'droppable' plugin (drag & drop interaction)

Tags: jquery, interactive

I'm building a website right now for a class project at [JimmiesAreRustled.com](http://JimmiesAreRustled.com), and in the How-To section, there are four images of bits of cereal that are currently draggable.

The problem lies in the face that the first bit of cereal ('.c1') is the only one that works with the drop interaction when you drop it to the mouth of the gorilla. The other 3 bits (.c2, .c3, .c4) don't work at all.

After that, I was wondering if there was any way to get the bits of cereal to disappear once they've been dropped?

here's the jQuery code I have for it:

```
$(".c1, .c2, .c3, .c4").draggable();

$(".invis1").droppable({
            over: function() {
                    $('.game').hide();
                    $('.game2').show();
                    $('embed').remove();
                    $('body').append('<embed src="../sounds/sound2.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
    });

$(".invis2").droppable({
            over: function() {
                    $('.game2').hide();
                    $('.game3').show();
                    $('embed').remove();
                    $('body').append('<embed src="../sounds/sound2.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
    });

$(".invis3").droppable({
            over: function() {
                    $('.game3').hide();
                    $('.game4').show();
                    $('embed').remove();
                    $('body').append('<embed src="../sounds/sound2.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
    });

$(".invis4").droppable({
            over: function() {
                    $('.game4').hide();
                    $('.game5').show();
                    $('embed').remove();
                    $('body').append('<embed src="../sounds/sound2.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
    });
```

- .c1, .c2, .c3, .c4 = bits of cereal
- .game divs = the new pages that hide/load the new images once the
  cereal is dropped
- .invis divs = the invisible box over the gorilla's mouth/target for cereal bits to be dropped

Comment: sure, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/p2npc/1/

it relies on the draggable/droppable plugin though, not sure if it's any help (sorry, today's my first time posting here, and my first time making those fiddle things)

Comment: nevermind, got it working. i had to take off the margins, and it worked. i still don't know how to make them disappear after they've been dragged to the target though.

Comment: awesome, let me know if you're able to get it or not. thank you for your effort too either way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely I think your problem is being caused by using margins to position your "cereal".

Try something like this:

```
.c1 {
    position: relative;
    top:-100px;
    left:200px;
}
.c2 {
    position: relative;
    top:-200px;
    left:200px;
}
.c3 {
    position: relative;
    top:-200px;
    left:700px;
}
.c4 {
    position: relative;
    top:-100px;
    left:700px;
}
```

To hide the cereal after its been "eaten":

```
$(".c1, .c2, .c3, .c4").draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    }
});

$(".invis1").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function () {
        $('.hide').hide();
    }
});
```

[**Simple working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2npc/4/)

Note: I started writing this before I saw your comment about the margins...

Comment: definitely works in the fiddle example, but when i added it to my site, it doesn't drag anymore (except it just disappears). any ideas?

Comment: @PhillipNguyen try removing `tolerance: "touch",`

Comment: still the same results. is there anything i could possibly supply you additionally to help me out?

Comment: @PhillipNguyen I'm stumped sorry man... The drop function shouldn't be firing when its not being dropped

Comment: i did, but it gave me the same result. i reverted back to absolute positioning for the c1, c2, etc. pieces currently (so i know positioning isn't affecting the error).

Comment: no problem, i'll try troubleshooting myself. thanks again though!

Comment: fixed it man. i just changed the class name from 'hide' to 'hideme' (guess hide activated something and caused it to disappear early), but now it works. i really can't thank you enough for your code & time.